# How to visualize decision tree in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, random-forest, decision-tree

I ran a RandomForestClassifier, and I would like to visualize the output (the decision tree) in jupyter notebook, but I keep getting an error.

```
rnd_clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, max_leaf_nodes=16, n_jobs=-1)
rnd_clf.fit(X,y) 
clf_graph=export_graphviz(rnd_clf,
            feature_names=X.columns,
            filled=True,
            rounded=True, 
            out_file=None)

graph=graphviz.Source(clf_graph)
graph.render("clf_graph")
```

I get the following error:

```
NotFittedError: This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

Why do I get a NotFittedError, even though I have fitted the RandomForestClassifier?

I did the same for the DecisionTreeClassifier, and I get a different error:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf = clf.fit(X,y)
clf_graph=export_graphviz(clf,
            feature_names=X.columns,
            filled=True,
            rounded=True, 
            out_file=None)

graph=graphviz.Source(clf_graph)
graph.render("clf")
```

I get the following error:

```
ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'clf'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```